# how to add the timestamp to filename on php image download

Tags: php

I have this string working

```
<td><?php if (isset($row["image"])) echo '<a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image']) .'" download="plexishop" > <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image']) .'"  class="rounded-circle" height="30" width="30" /> </a>'; ?></td>
```

when i click the picture on the page displayed the file downloaded is named "download.jpg" . I would like to rename it dynamically like "download.TIMESTAMP.jpg" .

Answer (score 0):

Try like this with [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to set the download file name as you wish.

```
header('Content-Disposition: filename="download.TIMESTAMP.jpg"');
```

So full code will be like this,

```
<td>
 <?php if (isset($row["image"])) 
  {
   header('Content-Disposition: filename="download.TIMESTAMP.jpg"');
   echo '<a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image']) .'" download="plexishop"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image']) .'"  class="rounded-circle" height="30" width="30" /> 
  </a>';
  }
 ?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

tested with Chrome and Firefox. Unfortunately IE doesn't support "download" attribute with data url

```
<?php
    $path = $row['image'] = 'upload/test.jpg';
    if (isset($path)) {
        $filename = 'file.' . time() . '.jpg'; // use any name you want
        $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $data = file_get_contents($path);
        echo '<a href="data:image/'.$type.';base64,'.base64_encode($data) .'" download="'.$filename.'" > <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, '.base64_encode($data) .'"  class="rounded-circle" height="20" width="20" /></a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: @SimonFranzen, you asking me?

Comment: You should add comment to OP not me. Besides, as said, IE doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

The `download` attribute for the link should work in your case. Let's build up the name

```
 download="download.'.date(c).'.jpg"
```

In your case

```
<td><?php if (isset($row["image"])) echo '<a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image']) .'" download="download.'.date(c).'.jpg" > <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image']) .'"  class="rounded-circle" height="30" width="30" /> </a>'; ?></td>
```